# docker service changes my route table

Tags: centos, docker

I encountered a deal problem:
I have *fedora24* as host and installed *centos7 minimal* as guest on *KVM*.
installed *docker* in guest, there is one NIC by ens3 name with 192.168.122.120 address
I can ssh to guest from host before *start docker service*.
in this step when i run `route -n` in guest,i would have 
`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.110.133.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens3`
now when i run `service docker start` in guest, i will lost ssh to guest by *ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.120 port 22: No route to host* and when i check rout table in guest machine, i faced
`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.110.133.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-c2a15a4ad6d2
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens3`
does know any one a logic reasonable?how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i opened a ticket in [github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24796) and the answer is:

> Pls remove the networks that are conflicting using docker network rm (or) stop the deamon, remove the /var/lib/docker/network directory and restart docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

When you install docker it adds a bridge to connect to the outside world and an IP class 172.x.0.0. You can change that by following the document here https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/ . If it disconnects you, look for the docker file /etc/default/docker or /etc/sysconfig/docker.

Comment: thanks alex,please first let me know is it a regular happen?, next, more interesting item that yesterday i hadn't this issue,I'm wondering if you provide me the reason.

Comment: I have not seen this happen on any live server, but theoretically if the bridge settings conflict with your enviroment, or your enviroment has changed and it brings the docker networking in conflict with it, then it can happen. I do not have enough information on your environment to fully explain why. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have a look over here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues, maybe someone else has already raised that issue.

Comment: I asked,it seems a bug

Comment: Did you solve the issue now?

Comment: not,I'm waiting to developer,it seems will solve in next realse.